# Cannot read in a .xlsx file in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, xlrd

Im having an issue trying to read in a .xlsx file in python. I keep receiving a File Not Found Error

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\me\place\stuff\date\date_Renewals.xlxs'

Here is what I have tried:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

cwd = os.getcwd()
date = input("What is the date? yyyymmdd ")
main_Dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sub_Dir = date + "\\" + date + "_Renewals.xlxs"

my_file = os.path.join(main_Dir,sub_Dir)
file = pd.read_excel(open(my_file))
```

When I print out my_file and manually verify it against the target directory, there are no errors.

get_cwd() returns:

```
C:\Users\me\place\stuff\
```

Manual Check:

```
C:\Users\me\place\stuff\date\date_Renewals.xlxs
```

printing the file path:

```
C:\Users\me\place\stuff\date\date_Renewals.xlxs
```

I have also tried using the xlrd library:

```
import os
import xlrd

cwd = os.getcwd()
date = input("What is the date? yyyymmdd ")
main_Dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sub_Dir = date + "\\" + date + "_Renewals.xlxs"

my_file = os.path.join(main_Dir,sub_Dir)
file = xlrd.open_workbook(my_file)
```

Yet I get the same result. Is there an issue with where my script is placed?

ie: in the C:\Users\me\place\stuff\

Directory

Comment: Typographic error in filename extension.

Answer (score 0):

*Don't have enough reputation to comment so I'll just post this as a partial answer...*

Your file names all end in **.xlxs** but the file extension for Microsoft Excel is **.xlsx**. Could that be the root of your problem?